# Get IPs of printers on Windows print server via SNMP\Script

Tags: linux, windows, print-server, icinga

I am setting up an icinga server for monitoring printer status via SNMP (toner levels, errors, that kind of thing).  All of the printers are accessible via a shared windows print server (Printer is added to client machines via \SERVER\Printer_Share).  While I am able to query the printers by IP directly via SNMP that tells me nothing about what their name.  Is it possible to query the Windows print server from Linux to produce an output similar to:

```
Shared Printer 1 -> IP_1
Shared Printer 2 -> IP_2
Shared Printer 3 -> IP_3
Shared Printer 4 -> IP_4
```

With this info I can then write a script to create icinga config files.  There are hundreds of printers so I am not doing this manually.  I'm not asking anyone to write a script for me but rather point me in the right direction.

Comment: Any reason you don't register the printer IPs in DNS?

Comment: We don't handle that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your options:

#### 1. evaluate registry data

- query for the subkeys of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers` to get a list of printers
- match the `port` value against `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Standard TCP/IP Port\Ports`
- evaluate the HostName and IPAddress values within the matching key

#### 2. use Powershell

- similar to 1. but use [`Get-Printer`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh918358.aspx) and [`Get-PrinterPort`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh918363.aspx) cmdlets to do retreive the respective data via a well-defined interface (you would need to use a Windows 8.1 or Server 2012 hosts to run the CMDlets, but the print server you're running them against could be an older version)

#### 3. use WMI

- similar to 1. and 2., but use the WMI [`Win32_Printer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class to retreive a list of printers and the [`Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class to retreive the `HostAddress` value in your WMI-query-capable language of choice (e.g. [VBScript](http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/printing/ports/scr_1171.asp))

Note that there is no uniform way to do this if your printers are using something vendor-specific instead of the `Standard TCP/IP Port`. You would need to go and figure it all out, although chances are that this information would be buried somehwere in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\<yourporttype>` registry subkey.

Note that while you theoretically could remote stuff from a Linux station using RPC, it probably would be a better idea to have NRPE transport the data (take a look at [NSClient++ using external scripts](http://nsclient.org/nscp/wiki/guides/nagios/external_scripts))

Comment: Thanks.  I got the output with VBS, put a text file in a share, and parsed it with Perl

Comment: @windowslinux this works too, of course. I mentioned NRPE since I understood that you wanted this information in Icinga. After giving your question a second read, It dawned on me that you just wanted to generate semi-static config files from this information.